# VBA code for using text from TextBox Control in email

Tags: vba

The Word doc has a button with this VBA code that sends it to a specific email address in the to field and another email address in the CC field. The CC field needs to be populated by an address that was filled in on the Word document inside a Content Control Text Box though. How do I define that variable in the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim xEmail As Object
    Dim xDoc As Document
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmail = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
    xDoc.Save
    With xEmail
        .Subject = "Click send"
        .Body = "Click send"
        .To = "sample@onmicrosoft.com"
        .CC = "employee email from textBox control"
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add xDoc.FullName
        .Display
    End With
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Set xEmail = Nothing
    Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's the first text box in your document:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim xEmail As Object
    Dim xDoc As Document
    Dim ccAddress As String 'Declare a string variable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmail = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    ccAddress = xDoc.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'Store the textbox text in the variable
    xDoc.Save
    With xEmail
        .Subject = "Click send"
        .Body = "Click send"
        .To = "sample@onmicrosoft.com"
        .CC = ccAddress 'pass it to the CC property
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add xDoc.FullName
        .Display
    End With
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Set xEmail = Nothing
    Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```